# How to center align social media tags using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, center

Hi i have a problem where every time i try to center align my social media images the are put in a horizontal listed way

this is the html code for the images

```
<div class="socialMediaIcon">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/nafis985">
        <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Logo">
    </a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com/nafis.rahman3">
        <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

And the CSS i have tried to center it with is this

```
.socialMediaIcon img {
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: I think we're going to need a demo because all you are doing at the moment is centering the images **in the links** not the centering the links themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by demo.

Comment: Use a tool like JSfiddle.net to **demo**nstrate the problem. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: imGaurav solved it thanks for the help and ill look up what you sent me for next time so i can give a better idea of what the question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.socialMediaIcon li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.socialMediaIcon li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.socialMediaIcon {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialMediaIcon">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/nafis985">
        <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Logo">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://facebook.com/nafis.rahman3">
        <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Logo">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked i'll accept the answer in 6 minutes since its not letting me now

Comment: use list (ul li) for best practices